# How to put a elisp list inside an elisp hash

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I have this working bit of code

```
(setq block_id nil)
(setq myHash (make-hash-table :test 'equal))
(puthash "5" "a" myHash)
(message (gethash "5" myHash))
```

it inserts a string in to the hash. and printss out "a" as its supposed
to do.
but how do I insert a list in to
the hash? I tried

```
(setq block_id nil)
(setq myHash (make-hash-table :test 'equal))
(puthash "5" ("list foo" "baa" "baz") myHash)
(message (gethash "5" myHash))
```

but I get a nil from the my emacs elisp repl.

Comment: What do you mean it isn't working? Please show how you're determining whether it worked or not.

Comment: edited question to give more context

Comment: The first argument to `message` should be a format string, not a list.

Comment: Try `(message "%S" (gethash "5" myHash))`

Comment: What does `block_id` have to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several errors. You're not quoting the list, so it's trying to call the string `"list foo"` as a function. Then you're calling `message` with the wrong type of argument.

```
(setq myHash (make-hash-table :test 'equal))
(puthash "5" '("list foo" "baa" "baz") myHash)
(message "%S" (gethash "5" myHash))
```

Comment: Alternatively, the OP intended to do `(list "foo" "baa" "baz")` instead, but just had sloppy punctuation placement.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Quite possibly. His original edit of the question had `(list "a" "b" "c")`.